# Get username and password from URL and paste into text box

Tags: c#, html, jquery

When I click on a url and open it in new tab I am trying to copy the username and password from the url and fill the username and password in a text box. I've searched Google but was unable to find a solution. Can anyone help please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would first like to address the fact that passing an uncrypted username and password with an URL is all kinds of unsafe.

But to address your question. From JavaScript you can access the url with `window.location`. This has multiple fields that you could use.

`window.location.host` and `window.location.hostname` will return "stackoverflow.com"

`window.location.href` will return the entire url "[Get username and password from URL and paste into text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61336907/get-username-and-password-from-url-and-paste-into-text-box)"

`window.location.pathname` will return you the part after the `host` "/questions/61336907/get-username-and-password-from-url-and-paste-into-text-box"

`window.location.search` would return you a parameter if that is part of the url. "https://stackoverflow.com?username=unsafe&password=password123" would return "?username=unsafe&password=password123".

You would then be able to use a regex to get the username and password from the url.

```
const match = window.location.search.match( /username=(.*)&password=(.*)/g )
// results in array [ "username=unsafe&password=password123", "unsafe", "password123" ]
// first array item match[0] is the full match
// second item match[1] is the first group (you can create a group by using round brackets)
// third item match[2] is the second group
const username = match[1];
const password = match[2];
```

I'm not a star with regex so there might be a better solution than I proposed.

But I hope this helps you with your issue.

Comment: i don't access the code, it is another website means third party. I have only the url , Username and password of website . how will I do this ?